# sorting a vector of pairs of doubles and pointers

Tags: c++

I have an std::vector of pairs of defined as the following structure:

```
template<typename Iterator>
struct Pair{
double a;
Iterator iterator;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can give a custom comparator to sort, as a lambda:

```
std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](const auto& lhs, const auto& rhs) {return lhs.a < rhs.a;});
```

Note: the above is C++14 syntax. If you wish it to be compliant with C++11, you simply change the `const auto&` in the above to the `const &` actual type of the vector, e.g. `const Pair<MyIter>&`.

Comment: You need to mention that this is C++17

Comment: It isn't, its C++14. In any case, its trivial to edit above to be C++11, this was more for brevity

Comment: Yes my mistake, but it should be mentioned anyway

Comment: OK, fair enough. I will edit

Comment: @Slava Why?  The Q is tagged C++ and that covers up to the current standard.

Comment: I have now edited my OP with the code I want to work with your implementations but it still gives me a long error when I try to compile. Did I implement it wrong?

Comment: `std::sort` does not return anything, it sorts the given vector in-place. Get rid of the `distPairs =` bit on your `sort` line

Comment: it seems I still get a long error from the compiler even after removing distPairs

Comment: The body of your comparator lambda is also wrong - it needs to be `{return lhs.a < rhs.a;}`

Comment: but in the sample code I uploaded my array of pairs is called distance_pairs

Comment: The code you actually need is `{return lhs.distance < rhs.distance;}` (I just saw that in your real type the member is called `distance` not `a`). Why? The lambda is not comparing the *arrays* but rather their *members*.

Comment: If I now want to extract an array of the first n iterators in the sorted list of pairs. How can I then do this easily? I.e. I want to extract this from my sorted list of pairs distance_pairs.

Comment: No. Something more like (after dist_pair is created) `std::vector<SetIterator> a; std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(a), k, [it = dist_pair.begin()](){ return (it++)->iterator;}); return a;`